# How would you say "for the longest time" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax

"For the longest time" is a name of a song by Billy Joel. And ReasonTV, a libertarian podcast, modified the lyrics of it to parody the Traveling Security Administration. George W. Bush founded it in response to 9/11 attacks to prevent people from getting guns and bombs into airplanes. And, basically, every year people in the US have to wait longer and longer for their luggage to be examined before they can get on an airplane, because every year there are additional checks. So, in that parody, ReasonTV says "*This year, you will be waiting for the longest time.*". How would you translate that to Latin?

Which word would you use for "*longest*"? There is a word meaning "*long*" which is cognate to English word "*long*", and that is "*longus*", so we might use its superlative "*longissimus*". But there is a also a word meaning "*long (time)*", and that is "*durans*". So, can we say "*durantissimus*"? But, in Croatian, you wouldn't use the word "*dugačak*" (long) here at all, you would use "*najviše vremena*" (the most time). So, can we use "*plurimus*" here? How is it in Latin?

Comment: Why not just use the superlative adverb diutissime (or the adverbial phrase quam diutissime, 'for the longest possible time')?

Comment: @cnread Never heard of "*diutissime*".

Comment: [Try PHI](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=quam+diutissime).

Comment: @cnread, please post this as an answer. You got my vote.